# Can't set Canvas ZIndex in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have code xaml like this: [image]

Now I change `Height` of `wp_2` to `450` and it's will bigger than `stackMain`, I set `Canvas.ZIndex="100"`in order to `wp_2` can display all but it still hidden a part by stackPanel:[image]  Does anyone know to fix it? Thank you all!

Comment: As your `WrapPanel` is inside `StackPanel` `Zindex` will be limited to the controls which are part of the StackPanel. You should try using `Grid` instead.

Comment: @Dishant I tried it but still doesn't work :)

Comment: Can you tell me the exact purpose that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Dishant I want the `yellow WrapPanel` can display all. Now my `yellow WrapPanel` have `Height=450` so that is larger than `Height` of `StackPanel` cover it, `yellow WrapPanel` just display a haft. You can see full width of this by the blue line below :) sorry for my english!

Comment: @Dishant I just edit a picture. Please check it

Comment: Please refer to my answer for this post.

Answer (score 0):

1.Give margin -50 top so that it begin from top(reinitialize from top).

2.In wrap panel every child control start from ending position of its elder.

(In this case yellow one starts from ending of red.)
 Give Margin="0,-50,0,0" to yellow one

```
<WrapPanel Background="Yellow" Height="50" Margin="0,-50,0,0" ></WrapPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the scenario that you mentioned using `Grid` is the best solution. Please refer to below code:

```
<Grid Background="Black">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <WrapPanel Name="Wp1" Background="Red"/>
        <WrapPanel Grid.Row="1" Name="Wp2" Background="Yellow" Height="500"/>
```

**EDITED**

As you want another layer for your WrapPanel than you can wrap it inside `Canvas`.

```
 <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Background="Black">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <WrapPanel Name="Wp1" Background="Red"/>
                <Canvas  Grid.Row="1" Panel.ZIndex="100" Height="500" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=mainGrid}">
                    <WrapPanel Name="Wp2" Background="Yellow" Height="400" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=mainGrid}"/>
                </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Comment: like your code, can I set `height` of `Wp2` larger than `Grid` height and `Wp2` still visible full height of this. Imagine it's like property `position: relative` in `CSS`

Comment: Please refer to my updated code. You can set Height to `Auto`

Comment: it seem like you've misunderstood what I said :). I want `WrapPanel` still a child of `Grid` but `WrapPanel` is another layer than `Grid`, upper layer than `Grid`. But I think it's impossible right? :))

Comment: I am still not sure what exactly you want to achieve by creating another layer? Whether you want to put it above your `wp_1` control or? I update my answer it that helps.

Comment: I think my question so ambiguous :). So I will create new simple question. Anyway I appreciate your help. Thank a lot! :). Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this?

```
<Grid Background="Aquamarine" Margin="0 0 0 -270">
        <Grid Background="Black" Margin="0 10 0 313">
            <StackPanel Margin="0 0 0 -500">
                <WrapPanel Background="Red" Height="50"/>
                <WrapPanel Background="Yellow" Height="450"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```